# Fraction modulo integer in sage?

Tags: python, sage

In Sage, I have some polynomials with rational coefficients, and I want to apply a congruence on these coefficients, for example `(1 + 7/2 x, 3)` should be sent to `1 + 1/2 x mod 3`.

I tried `mod_ui(n)` but it's no good because it returns an `int`. I have the code for the function in Python but I couldn't "translate it" into a Sage script. Here is the Python code:

```
def modPoly(c, k):
    if k == 0:
        print("Error in modPoly(c, k). Integer k must be non-zero")
    else:
        return [fracModulo.fracMod(x, k) for x in c]
```

Comment: Hi!  Can you be a little more precise about what you want to do?  I'm not seeing how `1+7/2x` becomes `1+1/x` - it is `(7/2)x` or `7/(2x)`, for instance?  (Also, you could turn an int into an `Integer` by doing `ZZ(your int)`.)

Comment: (See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1300935/fraction-modulo-integer-in-sage)

Comment: i'm sorry actually it's (7/2)x, so all I want is to have the coeffs of a polynomial modulo an integer: 7/2 mod 3 = 1/2

Answer (score 2):

You could define these two functions

```
def rat_mod_int(a, k):         # rational modulo integer
    return a.numerator() % (k * a.denominator()) / a.denominator()

def ratpoly_mod_int(p, k):     # polynomial modulo integer
    return p.parent()([rat_mod_int(a, k) for a in p])
```

Then the following works

```
sage: R.<x> = PolynomialRing(QQ)
sage: p = 7/2*x + 1
sage: ratpoly_mod_int(p, 3)
1/2*x + 1
```